# How to have a generic interface/abstract class (Java)?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have two classes, `LinkedListDeque` and `ArrayDeque`. They are both implementing all these methods:

```
public void addFirst(T item): //Adds an item of type T to the front of the deque.
public void addLast(T item): //Adds an item of type T to the back of the deque.
public boolean isEmpty(): //Returns true if deque is empty, false otherwise.
public int size(): //Returns the number of items in the deque.
public void printDeque(): //Prints the items in the deque from first to last, separated by a space. Once all the items have been printed, print out a new line.
public T removeFirst(): //Removes and returns the item at the front of the deque. If no such item exists, returns null.
public T removeLast(): //Removes and returns the item at the back of the deque. If no such item exists, returns null.
public T get(int index): //Gets the item at the given index, where 0 is the front, 1 is the next item, and so forth. If no such item exists, returns null. Must not alter the deque!
```

Moreover, both these classes should accept any generic type. Also, I changed the type of these items from `T` to `Item` for readability. From now on, whenever I say `Item`, I am referring to `T` in this block of code.

I was thinking of making an interface or abstract class called `Deque` where I would declare all these methods, then have my two classes implement or extend `Deque`. However, I am running into a problem.

The top line of my two classes are `public class SomethingDeque<Item>`. So, I am storing the deque of type `Item`. However, when I make my interface/abstract class using `public interface/abstract class Deque<Item>` and create these methods, Java throws an error when I try to override these methods. It keeps on changing the type of my parameters in `addLast` and `addFirst` from `Item` to `Object`. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Java is changing the type of your objects in your code? Or is your IDE doing it? Or do you mean in error messages? Post a minimal reproducible example as explained in the help center page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please create an [mre] and edit it into your question

Comment: Please don't switch from T to Item in the middle of your question. Either one is fine, but please be consistent!

Comment: it throws an error, changes `Item` to `Object`, you make an interface/abstract class, it is `T` but then `Item`... hard to understand - stick to one problem and start with one simple method (example: `public interface Deque<T> { void addFirst(T obj); }` and `public class ArrayDeque<T> implements Deque<T> { @Override public void addFirst(T obj) {  } }`)

Comment: It sounds like you've set up the generics wrong.  Please show the _complete_ first line of your classes, at the very least, including `implements ....`

Comment: Mb, I was writing this question in a hurry since I was running out of time with a stable interent connection so I wasn't able to fix the confusions. I have fixed this problem now though. I do not know what the problem was, I just deleted all the files and then restarted and it worked. Must've been a small thing I was overlooking.

Answer (score 4):

Both the `Deque` interface / abstract super class and the concrete implementations should be generic. E.g.:

```
public interface Deque<E> {
    void addFirst(E e);
    void addLast(E e);
    // other methods
}

public class ArrayDeque<E> implements Deque<E> {
    @Override
    public void addFirst(E e) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void addLast(E e) {
        // do something else
    }

    // fields, methods, etc.
}
```

As you can see, `ArrayDeque` has its own generic type. Since I don't want to add to the `T` vs `Item` confusion, I'm calling the generic type `E` for element. `E` is forwarded from the implementation class to the `Deque` interface.

This works as expected. In fact, if you have a look at the [OpenJDK's source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk20/tree/master/src/java.base/), you are going to find an [`ArrayDeque`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk20/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java) class and a [`Deque`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk20/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Deque.java) interface very similar to the ones above.